# Editing files of Xcode project from different Mac Application

Tags: xcode, applescript

I am new to scripting languages. I have a mac application which takes path of a particular file say it is a .h or .m file.Can I edit the .h or .m file using some script such as applescript/shell script etc.,

Comment: I’m not entirely sure I understand the question: are you asking if you can **edit** source code files used in an Xcode project with another application than Xcode?

Comment: Are you implying changing the source of a application? If so, you answer is no.. you cannot use xcode or any other application to change the source (.h .m file as you refer them to) of that application. It is impossible.

Comment: @kopischke : I want to edit source code files used in an Xcode project(proj 1) with another Xcode project(proj 2) in which i will take any file of  proj 1 as input. So can i do that

Comment: @simple drag proj 1 into proj 2 "groups and files". That should do the trick. I don't know why one would do that though..